# Specify position of body using CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is the code for my website:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.centered {
  /* Center entire body */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Training File Upload</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="centered">
    <div class="child">
      <br><br><br><br>
      <img src="logopng.png" style="width:450px;height:550px;">
      <form method="POST" action="http://68.227.63.30:100/upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <span>Choose midi files:</span> <br>
        <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple required/>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload for training" />

      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

I had the body centered on my website, however adding my logo dispositioned the body and I assume I'll have to specify coordinates maybe?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center your `<body>` or whichever child element wrapper by using [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) like you tried. The only change I would make would be to apply that flexbox centering to the `.child` element right underneath `<div class="centered">`.

Adding `flex-direction: column` to change it from a row to column seems to do the trick and center the `<form>` content much better with the logo. Without the logo src being there it's tough to tell if the alignment is "perfect" but if you need to tweak it some more I would add padding or margin to the `<form>` to achieve the centering you need with the logo.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.centered .child {
  /* Center entire body */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Training File Upload</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="centered">
    <div class="child">
      <br><br><br><br>
      <img src="logopng.png" style="width:450px;height:550px;">
      <form method="POST" action="http://68.227.63.30:100/upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <span>Choose midi files:</span> <br>
        <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple required/>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload for training" />

      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```